# Pasar el resultado de una consulta hecha con DataGridView a otro DataGridView

Tags: c#

espero alguien pueda apoyarme con la finalización de un código que estoy elaborando.
Lo que hace el codigo hasta ahora es realizar una consulta a una base de datos SQL Server por medio de un DataGridView con la ayuda de un foreach (hasta aquí todo bien) pero lo que intento hacer es que cada vez que lea la consulta el resultado vaya llenando un segundo DataGridView.

Mi código hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String PolizaNueva = "";
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in paraactuzalizarpolizas.Rows)
        {
            PolizaNueva = row.Cells["NUEVA_POLIZA"].Value.ToString();

            String ONCliente = "Select DS.NumPoliza, DS.Poliza, DS.Estado from DATOSSEGURO DS, CANCELACIONES CAN WHERE DS.NumPoliza=CAN.NumPoliza and CAN.NumPoliza='" + PolizaNueva + "'";
            SqlCommand OpNumClient = new SqlCommand();
            OpNumClient.Connection = MenuInicio.conexion;
            OpNumClient.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OpNumClient.CommandText = ONCliente;
            try
            {
                Leer = OpNumClient.ExecuteReader();
                Leer.Read();
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row2 in resultadosdelaconsulta.Rows)
                {
                    resultadosdelaconsulta[0, row2.Index].Value = Leer["NumPoliza"].ToString();
                    resultadosdelaconsulta[1, row2.Index].Value = Leer["Poliza"].ToString();
                    resultadosdelaconsulta[2, row2.Index].Value = Leer["Estado"].ToString();
                }
                Leer.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Leer.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Error al optener datos" + ex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es que el foreach recorre todo el DataGridView. Así que ese no se debe de utilizar, Lo que debo hacer es llenar un DataGridView y solo tengo que ir llenando las filas… es muy simple hacer esto. Dejo la solución por si alguien mas le interesa o llega a tener la misma pregunta.

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String PolizaNueva = "";
        int x = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in paraactuzalizarpolizas.Rows)
        {
            PolizaNueva = row.Cells["NUEVA_POLIZA"].Value.ToString();

            String ONCliente = "Select DS.NumPoliza, DS.Poliza, DS.Estado from DATOSSEGURO DS, CANCELACIONES CAN WHERE DS.NumPoliza=CAN.NumPoliza and CAN.NumPoliza='" + PolizaNueva + "'";
            SqlCommand OpNumClient = new SqlCommand();
            OpNumClient.Connection = MenuInicio.conexion;
            OpNumClient.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OpNumClient.CommandText = ONCliente;
            try
            {
                Leer = OpNumClient.ExecuteReader();
                Leer.Read();
                resultadosdelaconsulta.Rows.Add(Leer["NumPoliza"].ToString(), Leer["Poliza"].ToString(), Leer["Estado"].ToString());
                Leer.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Leer.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Error al actualizar poliza" + ex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```